# how to secure MySQL server?

Tags: windows, mysql, ssl, openssl

looking for a security to secure MySQL server. i am trying SSL using OpenSSL but I have no idea on how to do it for Windows without the shell command line. are they any more direct or easier security for MySQL server? anyone have any idea? thanks.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "secure MySQL". Do you mean the entire server or just remote connections?

Comment: just remote connections

Answer (score 0):

JCX,

There is a good section of the MySQL Manual which covers using SSL (either yaSSL or OpenSSL).  It can be found here:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/secure-connections.html

Chris

Answer (score 0):

Chris Calendar's blog has a good post that walks through the complete steps for setting up SSL for MySQL on Windows.  You will have to use the Command Prompt, though.

http://www.chriscalender.com/?p=448

Answer (score 0):

These days my tool of choice for this is [HeidiSQL](http://www.heidisql.com/), which will allow you to use an SSL connection without the need for other software. I use it regularly for managing a MySQL instance on a remote Linux machine from my Windows workstation.